# Move QScrollBar off of QTextBrowser/QTextEdit

Tags: qt

There must be some way to do this with the stylesheet feature? Changing the margin maybe? I don't know much about positioning with css, just how to change colors and the like. Or do I have to make a separate QScrollArea? Thanks in advance~

Comment: You can disable scroll bar programmatically

Comment: I don't want to disable it, I want to move it next to the QTextBrowser so it doesn't block any text and also just for the aesthetic.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Something like this: http://puu.sh/7X86b.png As you can see, the QScrollBar is next to the QTextEdit instead of directly on it like in this picture: http://puu.sh/7X8a7.png

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell in that second picture, but it's actually on the QTextEdit.

Comment: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-8e7e0fb0-d01e-4860-8324-19a820a7177c